# sending mail with php to enterprise domain

Tags: php, email

I am using this code to send mail with php http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-35146-e-mail-envoyer-un-e-mail-en-php.html#ss_part_4 . This code works great when I send email to the popular servers (gmail, hotmail, etc.) . The problem is that when I try to send it to a 'private' server, well, I don't know how to call it. I'm referring here to enterprise domain, like someone@some-enterprise.com. The mail does not reach the destination. Why is this happening and how can I solve this proble;

Comment: spam filters? maybe you need to add proper SPF record to sender domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). This is a good way to work with emails through PHP when your project need more accuracy.  I hope it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems comes from a spam filter. You have to speak to your company's system administrator (the one which is responsable for emails)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set up dkim,domain key signature,spf for your mail server then you should use some php mail module like phpMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ so your email would not go to spam.